# Error: object 'dodge' not found - Plot not working anymore

Tags: r, position-dodge

This graph was working perfectly before, and now it is giving me the error "Error: object 'dodge' not found". It used to work perfectly fine, and I didn't change the code. Does someone have any idea of what could be going on?

Thank you.

Here is the code and what the graph used to look like.

```
library(lfe)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(data.table) 
library(lfe) 
library(texreg) # not working
library(hdm) 
library(parallel)
library(coefplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(broom.helpers)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
#library(devtools)
#devtools::install_github('cttobin/ggthemr')
library(ggthemr)
#devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)

################################################################################ 
#   Plot
################################################################################ 
plot_applied <- ggplot(results, 
                        aes(x = Outcome, y = Coefficient, color=Variable)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, 
             colour = gray(1/2), lty = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Outcome, 
                 y = Coefficient, color=Variable, shape=Variable), show.legend = TRUE, size = 2.5, stroke = 1.2, position = position_dodge(width = dodge)) + 
  
  geom_linerange(aes(x = Outcome, 
                     ymin = conf.low_90,
                     ymax = conf.high_90, color=Variable),
                 lwd = 1, position = position_dodge(width = dodge), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = Outcome, 
                     ymin = conf.low_95,
                     ymax = conf.high_95, color=Variable),
                 lwd = 1/2, position = position_dodge(width = dodge), show.legend = TRUE)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=desired_order, labels = labels) + # bottom to top = left to right 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#f5ad9f", "#91c8e3", "#226bb4"), name = "Treatment:", labels = c("Flyer: Complexity", "Flyer: Knowledge", "Welcome letter"), guide = guide_legend(reverse=T)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17, 18), name = "Treatment:", labels = c("Flyer: Complexity", "Flyer: Knowledge", "Welcome letter"), guide = guide_legend(reverse=T)) +
  #scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 21, 19), name = "Data source:", labels = c("Survey W2\n(N=2,551)", "Survey W1\n(N=3,859)")) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(label = NULL) +
  ylim(-0.1,0.8)+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=12)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")# +

plot_applied
```

I tried tracing back the error, and this is what I get.

```
> traceback()
5: list2(...)
4: ggproto(NULL, PositionDodge, width = width, preserve = arg_match0(preserve, 
       c("total", "single")))
3: position_dodge(width = dodge)
2: layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint, 
       position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
       params = list2(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
1: geom_point(aes(x = Outcome, y = Coefficient, color = Variable, 
       shape = Variable), show.legend = TRUE, size = 2.5, stroke = 1.2, 
       position = position_dodge(width = dodge))
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to assign a numeric value to your `dodge` object (for example `dodge <- 0.9`) before making your plot